# How to calculate time difference between typing the URL and opening of that URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate the time difference between the user typing the URL and opening up the website or else refreshing the current page. Is there any way to do this using Javascript ?

Comment: You want to know how long it takes someone to type the URL before hitting it? No, there's no way to measure that. That's something that the browser would have to do.

Comment: Your website doesn't even "exist" while the url is being typed, so no.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet  After hitting enter, or a reload button, whether or not the URL is valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no. There's no way to tell how long it takes someone to type your URL, you simply aren't in the scope of your website and there's no way to tell how long it actually takes. But the next best thing is the load time, here's an example of how to do that:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var timerStart = Date.now();
        </script>
        <!-- do all the stuff you need to do -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- put everything you need in here -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {
                 console.log("Time until DOMready: ", Date.now()-timerStart);
             });
             $(window).load(function() {
                 console.log("Time until everything loaded: ", Date.now()-timerStart);
             });
        </script>
    </body>
```